# Asp.Core 2.1 [ApiController] attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I haven't written api's for a while (last time in asp.core 2.0) so today decided to create new one in .core 2.1 version and unfortunately find out that my Actions don't work like they used to work in previos version.

After few hours I figure out that problem cause the `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and since`[ApiController]` doesn't work with out it I comment them both and every thing works FINE.
**So can anyone explain me what should I do to make this code work with '[ApiController]' unconnebt  and the same action URLs calls ?

```
   //[Route("api/[controller]")]
   //[ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("api/[controller]")]
        public string A1()
        {
            return "A1()";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string A2(int id)
        {
            return $"A2(int {id})";
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string A3(string p1,string p2)
        {
            return $"A3(string {p1},string {p2})";
        }
        [Route("api/[controller]/A4/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string A4(int id)
        {
            return $"A4(int {id})";
        }
        [HttpGet("api/[controller]/A5/{id}")]
        public string A5(int id)
        {
            return $"A5(int {id})";
        }
    }
```

`
StartUp.css

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{……///code
      app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
    }
```

1. https://localhost:5001/api/Test
2. https://localhost:5001/api/Test/A2?id=1
3. https://localhost:5001/api/Test/A2/1
4. https://localhost:5001/api/Test/A3?p1=test&p2=test
5. https://localhost:5001/api/Test/A4/1
6. https://localhost:5001/api/Test/a5/1

**Test1**:
I made changes based on @chris-pratt answer

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("")]
        public string A1()
        {
            return "A1()";
        }

        [HttpGet("A2")]
        [HttpGet("A2/{id}")]
        public string A2([FromQuery]int id)
        {
            return $"A2(int {id})";
        }

        [HttpGet("A3")]
        public string A3([FromQuery]string p1, [FromQuery]string p2)
        {
            return $"A3(string {p1},string {p2})";
        }


        [HttpGet("A4")]
        public string A4([FromQuery]int id)
        {
            return $"A4(int {id})";
        }

        [HttpGet("A5")]
        public string A5([FromQuery]int id)
        {
            return $"A5(int {id})";
        }
    }
```

Url calls:

1. ok
2. ok
3. id=0
4. ok
5. 404
6. 404

5&6 is the same now

Comment: for #3 you're telling the router to bind the {id} in the route pattern to the method param, but then telling the method param to bind to the [FromQuery]... and it appears the [FromQuery] is winning (you don't have an ?id=1 in #3 url).  #4 and #5 URLs don't match the route path (the url ends with A4/1 but the route says "A4"... you probably meant to have Route("A4/{id}") and then remove that [FromQuery] in the method signature)

Answer (score 1):

Neither `[Route("api/[controller]")]` nor `[ApiController]` are your actual issue. The `[Route]` attribute on the controller class level specifies a route prefix for all actions in that controller. When you take it off, you're falling back to the default route in MVC, `/{controller}/{action}/{id?}`.

It's also important to realize that using attribute routing overrides the default route *at the level it's applied*. In other words, if you don't apply `Route` to your controller, then actions there will use the default route. If you apply the `Route` attribute or one of the HTTP method attributes like `HttpGet` to an action, then just that individual action will use the custom attribute route. However, if you do apply the `Route` attribute to your controller, the *all actions in the controller will use attribute routing, even if you don't explicitly apply an attribute*. Therefore, it's important that you give each action it's own unique route.

Your first issue is that you've applied this same route to some of your actions as you've applied to the controller. The end result is that the route for that action ends up being actually `/api/test/api/test`. You only need to specify the portion of the route that's after the prefix, i.e. `[HttpGet("a1")]`. If you want it to just be the prefix, with no additional route segment of its own, then you simply use an empty route, i.e. `[HttpGet("")]` or just `[HttpGet]`. Just make sure you only do that once per HTTP method.

Now the difference with `[ApiController]` applied is that, among other things, it switches the default binding from `FromForm` to `FromBody`. However, that will only apply to reference types as params, like classes. Value types like strings will be unbound. Since you want to get those from the query string, apparently, then you should add `[FromQuery]` to those:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string A3([FromQuery]string p1, [FromQuery]string p2)
```

Finally, you also have a bunch of duplicate routes. As I outlined above, not specifying a route is the same as specifying an empty route on the action, which then means all you have is the route prefix set on the controller. You need to ensure that each action has a unique route it responds to. For example, the above method should actually have something like `[HttpGet("a3")]`, which would then give you you're intended route of `/api/test/a3?p1=test&p2=test`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and detail explanation. Unfortunately if controller have `[ApiController]` attribute  than each action should have defined route or InvalidOperationException error appears.
I made some changes in my code  according to your answer changes which you may see in updated question but still 3/6 URLs are not working.

Answer (score 1):

For 5&6, you do not need to use `[FromQuery]`.For 2&3, if you still would like to use Query string and attribute routing together, you need to set `SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters` property to true to disable the default inference rules. Refer to [Binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference).

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{ 
   options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
});
```

The web api controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpGet("")]
public string A1()
{
    return "A1()";
}

[HttpGet("A2")]
[HttpGet("A2/{id}")]
public string A2(int id)
{
    return $"A2(int {id})";
}

[HttpGet("A3")]
public string A3([FromQuery]string p1, [FromQuery]string p2)
{
    return $"A3(string {p1},string {p2})";
}


[HttpGet("A4/{id}")]
public string A4(int id)
{
    return $"A4(int {id})";
}

[HttpGet("A5/{id}")]
public string A5(int id)
{
    return $"A5(int {id})";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive made some changes to your code please see my proposed solution. The routing is now setup that every method on the controller will form as the route name and the `[FromRoute]` tags on your parameters indicate that they will come from the route specified beneath the HTTP Verb.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public string A1()
    {
        return "A1()";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public string A2([FromRoute]int id)
    {
        return $"A2(int {id})";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{p1}/{p2}")]
    public string A3([FromRoute]string p1,[FromRoute]string p2)
    {
        return $"A3(string {p1},string {p2})";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public string A4([FromRoute]int id)
    {
        return $"A4(int {id})";
    }
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string A5([FromRoute]int id)
    {
        return $"A5(int {id})";
    }
}
```

Your route should now look something like http://localhost:5200/api/test/A2/5 as an example